# Going over the Microsoft Edge Read Aloud Speed Limit

Tags: microsoft-edge, text-to-speech

After long research, I've created my optimal ebook (Epub) reader. As the main device, I'm basically using a Windows 10 Tablet and Microsoft Edge as the (Epub) reader.

It's great and amazing. But... I would like to have better control over the "Read aloud" settings. Including:

1. Going over the 2x speed limit of the "Read aloud" function
2. Reducing the break duration between paragraphs of the "Read aloud" function.

Does anyone have any idea on how it can be done? (didn't find any documentation on relevant registry keys or settings files)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently there is no way to going over 2X speed limit of the Read aloud function and there is no any option available for reducing the break between paragraphs in MS Edge.

Thanks for providing your valuable feedback to us.

We will try to submit both feature requests to Microsoft Developers.

Once we submit the request successfully, We will provide you a link of that.

you can try to give your **Up vote** to that feedback requests.

If this request get enough votes than Microsoft developers can consider to add these features in future updates for MS Edge.

Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Did you submit any request?

Comment: I’d just like to second that 2x is too slow to be useful, and I’d much prefer an open-ended scale or at least the option to go up to about 4x. Thank you!